# CKEditor, create a dropdown button

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

From Drupal 8, I'm looking for create a very sample CKEditor plugin (CKEditor version 4.8). This plugin allows the user (me) to add quickly specifics tag in the text.

After some google search, I find how add a simple button in the CKEditor pannel, but I don't find any example for add a dropdown list in the CKEditor pannel.

Below, my code for add a simple button :

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'addtime', {
    icons: 'addtime',
    init: function( editor ) {

        editor.addCommand( 'insertTimestamp', {
            exec: function( editor ) {
                var now = new Date();
                editor.insertHtml( 'The current date and time is: <em>' + now.toString() + '</em>' );
            }
        });
        editor.ui.addButton( 'addtime', {
            label: 'Insert Timestamp',
            command: 'insertTimestamp',
            toolbar: 'insert'
        });
    }
});
```

Now I want add a dropdown list instead the sample button "addtime". By example, a dropdown list with theses options `"add <a>" / "add <b>" / "add <c>"` and when I click on the option `"add <b>"` then the text `"<b>"` is added to the text.

Comment: This sounds like more of a general JavaScript question : CKEditor plug-in dev and not drupal.

Comment: I thinked there was a "Drupal way" for do what I want, but you're certainly right

Comment: I mean, you need to create a CKEditor js plug-in first before Drupal enters the picture (telling Drupal how to find the plug-in)

Comment: I close this post

Comment: this is not a drupal issue

Comment: @spacecodeur how come this is not a Drupal issue? There must be a way to create what the OP wants by adding it in a Drupal hook or Drupal behaviors